# On windows, the CORS preflight OPTIONS request is sent and returned, but then the PUT request will hang 'pending' indefinitely

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, express

I have been developing node.js web and desktop applications that communicate with each other via Express.js.

The web app will send CORS PUT requests to the desktop client, and then the desktop client will perform some set of functionality.

On Mac, the CORS preflight OPTIONS request will be sent and returned, and then the PUT request will be properly sent and returned. On windows however, the CORS preflight OPTIONS request is sent and returned, but then the PUT request will hang 'pending' indefinitely. There is no indication that the request has been received by the desktop client, not that it has simply failed to send a response. This will occur using IE10+, Chrome, or Firefox.

Comment: Can you show the raw requests/responses?

Answer (score 0):

Does the PC happen to have Sophos installed on it? Sophos has this awesome feature where it makes your life a living hell.

I only have a screenshot of the preference on Mac, but I assume you can find a similar preference pane.

[image]